# Is this integral for a PDE equation solvable?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Following the approach in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756267/the-general-solution-to-the-heat-equation), for 
$$\phi (t) = \frac{A} {1 +\exp\Big(B (C+ D t) \Big)} $$

I derived

$$u = \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\int_{\mu=0}^{\infty} \frac{A} {1 +\exp\Big(B (C+ D (t - \frac{x^2}{4\kappa\mu^2})) \Big)} e^{-\mu^2} d\mu \\ - \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\int_{\mu=_0}^{x/2\sqrt{4\kappa t}} \frac{A} {1 +\exp\Big(B(C+ D (t - \frac{x^2}{4\kappa \mu^2})) \Big)} e^{-\mu^2} d\mu$$

However, I cannot make the integration to proceed further.